# Determine the equivalent capacitance for the group of capacitors in the drawing. Let all capacitors be the same where C = 40.0 µF

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits

[image]

Determine the equivalent capacitance for the group of capacitors in the drawing. Let all capacitors be the same where C = 40.0 µF.

Comment: I've added the homework-and-exercises tag. In the future, please use this tag on this type of question.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the formula for

- capacitance of two capacitors in parallel
- capacitance for two capacitors in series

then you can do a simple step by step simplification of the diagram as below. I haven't shown all the steps but start with calculating the capacitance of the two caps in series at the top left of the rectangle (= capacitance shown in blue), then calculate the parallel capacitance of the 'blue' capacitor and the top right diagonal capacitor (= capacitance shown in green). Etc....

[image]